# Cannot query an alias table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm doing something like:

```
SELECT T1.NAME, T2.DATE
    FROM T1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT * FROM OTHERTABLE
) AS T2 ON T2.USERID = T1.USERID
```

Which works, but if I query the alias table, I get an error saying that T2 is an invalid object name.

Example:

```
SELECT 
T1.NAME, 
T2.DATE,
CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM T2 WHERE T2.THISFIELD = T1.THISFIELD) THEN 'HELLO'
    ELSE 'BYE'
END AS COMMENT -- THIS ALSO FAILS
    FROM T1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT * FROM OTHERTABLE
) AS T2 ON T2.USERID = T1.USERID
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T2) > 0
```

I thought that's what I did, "create" T2. Is there any way I can use T2 like such ?

My goal is to scrape all the related data from `OTHERTABLE` once because I'll have many CASE in the SELECT clause depending whether data exists in T2 or not. I don't want to do EXISTS for every field since that'll launch a new query in a huge table everytime.

Comment: You are out of scope your `select count...` is another temporary table which doesnt have access to the alias

Comment: I think you are a bit confused,its not going to be faster if you try to outsmart the optimiser..Left Join properly othertable , not in a subqery and then use coalesce or other function ot get what you need even inner join is enough.Where select count is a really convoluted way to chase your own tail And correlated queries are one of the fastest way to get data in a join,they wont launch a huge table everytime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query using a sub-query of `SELECT * FROM OTHERTABLE` which doesn't make sense. You can modify it like;

```
SELECT 
T1.NAME, 
T2.DATE,
...

FROM T1
    JOIN OTHERTABLE T2 ON T2.USERID = T1.USERID
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OTHERTABLE ) > 0
```

You cannot use a sub-query multiple times in the same query. Instead use a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms175972.aspx) for that purpose. T2 is a CTE in the following example.

```
;WITH T2 AS
(
   SELECT UserId, col1, col2, [Date]
   FROM OtherTable
)
SELECT T1.NAME, T2.DATE
FROM T1
    JOIN T2 ON T2.USERID = T1.USERID
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T2) > 0
```